# why i getting null value in fragment using bundle

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm using bundle for data transfer between `fragment`, sender part is ok 
but at receiving, I'm getting `null` value at the bundle.

I have tried everything and I don't find any error but still not getting
I've Tried every possible solution. Please let me know what I'm making mistake here.

At first fragment, I'm sending object type data and int type data.

FirsrtFragment.java

```
       lay_upcoming.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            bundle = new Bundle();
            eventFragment = new EventFragment();
            bundle.putInt("img_id", img_id2);
            eventFragment.setArguments(bundle);

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up).addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.fragment_container, new EventFragment()).commit();
        }
    });
```

This is My SecondFragment.java

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    intiView();

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_detail_fragment, container, false);
    bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        img_id = getArguments().getInt("img_id");

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Bundle is Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the null value? Can you post the error log?

Comment: In SecondFragment.java at  if condition it showing me bundle=null

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the fragment where you set the bundle. But you are using a new Fragment. Change the code as below

```
lay_upcoming.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        bundle = new Bundle();
        eventFragment = new EventFragment();
        bundle.putSerializable("Data", (Serializable) data2);
        Log.i("DAta", String.valueOf(img_id2));
        Log.i("DAta", String.valueOf(img_id2));
        bundle.putInt("img_id", img_id2);
        eventFragment.setArguments(bungetFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up).addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.fragment_container, eventFragment).commit(); // change new EventFragment() to eventFragment
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new fragment instead of the one you already created and passed arguments: `replace(R.id.fragment_container, new EventFragment())`.

Just use the `eventFragment` you already created: `replace(R.id.fragment_container, eventFragment)`.